# wpf button click as keyboard output

Tags: wpf, button, keyboard, virtual

I have two button name "A", and "B" want to click them equal to click keyboard A and B buttons.
So any one can give me a quick way to achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: eg. two button button 'a' and button 'b' in window. and i open a text file. and click button 'a' , text show a too. like virtual keyboard only two key a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it the following way. First add event handler for the key down event of window or some other parent container:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" Width="525"> [...]
```

And the event handler:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Key == Key.A)
            ButtonA.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
        else if (e.Key == Key.B)
            ButtonB.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have already try. but it can't work. i want to click button name 'a' , then in doc file or text file show 'a'.